# How to add zoom-in and zoom-out buttons in dc.geoChoroplethChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, geojson, dc.js

I wanted to add zooming effect to `dc.geoChoroplethChart()`. I am able to get Zoom-in and Zoom-out behavior with wheelmouse. I achieved with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246125/how-to-add-zoom-effect-into-dc-geochoroplethchart/24407851#24407851) example. But, how to achieve this using Zoom-in and Zoom-out buttons? I tried multiple multiple ways to do this seeing d3 examples, but ended up unsuccessful and messing the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function for moving selected nodes with the arrow keys (i.e translating)

```
function keydown()//-ability to move selected nodes with arrows
{
    if (!d3.event.metaKey) switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 38: nudge( 0, -1); break; // UP
    case 40: nudge( 0, +1); break; // DOWN
    case 37: nudge(-1,  0); break; // LEFT
    case 39: nudge(+1,  0); break; // RIGHT
}
```

Nudge function :

```
function nudge(dx, dy) //-use arrow keys to nudge selection
{   
    force.stop(); //-stops the force layout
    tick(); //-calls tick

    nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.selected; })            
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x += dx; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y += dy; });
}
```

You can use this so instead of translate, use scale