# Zoom effect into dc.geoChoroplethChart

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, zooming, dc.js

I'm using the dc.js Library to create a Geo Choropleth map and couldn't add the ability to zoom in or out and move the map.

I already tried the code from the following thread: [How to add zoom effect into dc.geoChoroplethChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246125/how-to-add-zoom-effect-into-dc-geochoroplethchart)

But the zoom function didn't work. Moving the map works but if I try to zoom in or out, the map disappears. Is there an other way to add a zoom functionality to the map?

Comment: I found the issue why it didn't worked. You have to remove the .scaleExtent([height/2, 8 * height] line.